# Display username on other page? Code error

Tags: c#, azure, uwp

The code has already been created but is giving me a small error. This is the code used for saving the username in the first login page.

```
public void SaveSetting(string userLabel, string userNamelabel)
    {
        ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        //Saving your setting  
        localSettings.Values[userLabel] = textBoxUsername.Text;
    }
```

On the home page I have

```
public home()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        UserNameLabelBox.Text = ReadSetting(userLabel);
    }



private string ReadSetting(string userLabel)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        //Reading and returning your setting value
        var value = localSettings.Values[userLabel];
        if (value != null)
            return value.ToString();
        else
            return userLabel;
```

The line below initialize component is highlighted red and says "userLabel does not exist in this current context".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you never set the value from the variable `userLabel` on your home page to a variable that can be seen from another page.

I would add a public global variable to your login page called `public string globalUserLabel ;` then I would call that in your home page home method.

like:

```
public string globalUserLabel;

public void SaveSetting(string userLabel, string userNamelabel)
    {
        globalUserLabel = userLabel;
        ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        //Saving your setting  
        localSettings.Values[userLabel] = textBoxUsername.Text;
    }


public home()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        UserNameLabelBox.Text = ReadSetting(LoginPage.globalUserLabel );
    }
```

**OR**

you can create a `globalVariable` class and store your user information in this class and call this specific class when necessary.

That would look like

```
public class globalVariable {

public string userlabel {get; set;};

}
```

then

```
public void SaveSetting(string userLabel, string userNamelabel)
    {
        globalVariable.userlabel = userLabel;
        ApplicationDataContainer localSettings =
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        //Saving your setting  
        localSettings.Values[userLabel] = textBoxUsername.Text;
    }
```

and finally

```
public home()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        UserNameLabelBox.Text = ReadSetting(globalVariable.userlabel);
    }
```

Comment: The public string added to the login page is now giving the same error. Though the "UserNameLabelBox.Text = ReadSetting(LoginPage.globalUserLabel" worked.

Comment: Are you trying to assign a value to 'public string globalUserLabel;' outside of the SaveSetting method?

Comment: Ok I got it. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Okay in your home page you will need to make an instance of your MainPage class

Comment: MainPage mainPage = new MainPage ();

Comment: Then you should be able to call it with mainPage .globalVariable .

Comment: Your welcome, If you don't mind if this answer was helpful could you mark it as the accepted solution so others can reference it.